# Arduino LED Cube 4x4x4 Any Ideas how to Fix

Tags: pandas, arduino, cube, led

```
// Connections
int mreset = 10;
int shift = 11;
int store = 12;
int data = 13;
int taster = 9;
int a, tasterstatus = 0;

// Delays
int tasterdelay = 250;


int fast = 5;
int stage1 = 1000;
int stage2 = 1000;


unsigned long time_now = 0;

// Pattern
int firstlevel[24]  = {1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0};
int secondlevel[24] = {0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0};
int thirdlevel[24]  = {0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0};
int fourthlevel[24] = {0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0};

int leftside[24]    = {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
int ndleftside[24]  = {1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
int ndrightside[24] = {1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
int rightside[24]   = {1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0};

int backside[24]    = {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
int ndbackside[24]  = {1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
int ndfrontside[24] = {1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
int frontside[24]   = {1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0};

int cube1[24]       = {1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
int cube2_1[24]     = {1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
int cube2_2[24]     = {0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
int bigcube1_1[24]  = {1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0};
int bigcube1_2[24]  = {0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0};

int cube3_1[24]     = {0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
int cube3_2[24]     = {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
int cube4[24]       = {0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};

int cube5_1[24]     = {1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
int cube5_2[24]     = {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
int cube6[24]       = {1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};

int cube7_1[24]     = {0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0};
int cube7_2[24]     = {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0};
int cube8[24]       = {0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0};

int custom1[24]     = {1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0};
int custom2[24]     = {0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0};

void setup() {

//Set Outputs
  pinMode(shift , OUTPUT);
  pinMode(store , OUTPUT);
  pinMode(data , OUTPUT);
  pinMode(mreset , OUTPUT);
  pinMode(taster , INPUT);

// Set Shift Register Master Reset On/Off
  digitalWrite(mreset, LOW);
  digitalWrite(store, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(mreset, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(store, LOW);
}
void loop() {
//Waiting for Button PRess
  tasterstatus = digitalRead(taster);
  if (tasterstatus == HIGH) {
    a++;
    delay(tasterdelay);
  }
  //Choose Pattern
  if (a == 1) {
    pattern1();
  }
  if (a == 2) {
    pattern2();
  }
}

void pattern1() {
//Equate Millis with time_now
  time_now = millis();
  // First Sample for LED Cube
  for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
    digitalWrite(shift, LOW);
    digitalWrite(data, firstlevel[i]);
    digitalWrite(shift, HIGH);

  }
  digitalWrite(store, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(store, LOW);
// "Delay"
  while (millis() < time_now + stage1) {
    tasterstatus = digitalRead(taster);
    // Checking Button State
    if (tasterstatus == HIGH) {
      delay(tasterdelay);
      a++;
      pattern2();
    }
  }
  // Clearing Shift Registers with Master Reset
  digitalWrite(mreset, LOW);
  digitalWrite(store, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(mreset, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(store, LOW);

  time_now = millis();
  for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
    digitalWrite(shift, LOW);
    digitalWrite(data, secondlevel[i]);
    digitalWrite(shift, HIGH);

  }
  digitalWrite(store, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(store, LOW);

  while (millis() < time_now + stage1) {
    tasterstatus = digitalRead(taster);
    if (tasterstatus == HIGH) {
      delay(tasterdelay);
      a++;
      pattern2();
    }
  }
  digitalWrite(mreset, LOW);
  digitalWrite(store, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(mreset, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(store, LOW);

  time_now = millis();
  for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
    digitalWrite(shift, LOW);
    digitalWrite(data, thirdlevel[i]);
    digitalWrite(shift, HIGH);

  }
  digitalWrite(store, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(store, LOW);

  while (millis() < time_now + stage1) {
    tasterstatus = digitalRead(taster);
    if (tasterstatus == HIGH) {
      delay(tasterdelay);
      a++;
      pattern2();
    }
  }
  digitalWrite(mreset, LOW);
  digitalWrite(store, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(mreset, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(store, LOW);
  time_now = millis();
  for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
    digitalWrite(shift, LOW);
    digitalWrite(data, fourthlevel[i]);
    digitalWrite(shift, HIGH);

  }
  digitalWrite(store, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(store, LOW);

  while (millis() < time_now + stage1) {
    tasterstatus = digitalRead(taster);
    if (tasterstatus == HIGH) {
      delay(tasterdelay);
      a++;
      pattern2();
    }
  }
  digitalWrite(mreset, LOW);
  digitalWrite(store, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(mreset, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(store, LOW);

}
void pattern2() {
  time_now = millis();
  for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
    digitalWrite(shift, LOW);
    digitalWrite(data, cube1[i]);
    digitalWrite(shift, HIGH);

  }
  digitalWrite(store, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(store, LOW);
}`enter code here
```

My Problem Is that when i press the button in Pattern1, Pattern2 Starts 1x time, after that Pattern1 continues where i pressed the Button, runs 1x trough, and after that pattern 2 repeats normaly. Any ideas how to fix it ? Like when i press the Button First Pattern1 repeats infinity as it should. But when i press it again, while Pattern1 is running, its goes to Pattern2 as it should, but it only repeats Pattern2 1x time, than it resumes pattern1, where i pressed the button, and then it repeats pattern2 as it should.

So the Main Problem is that Pattern1 Runs 1x time in pattern2;

Thanks for help

Comment: The problem is that you have that while loop in pattern1() where you check the button, increment a, and then call pattern2().  It calls pattern2 once, and then returns to that point to finish pattern 1.  I don't think you can fix this code.  You will have to rewrite the whole thing so that the patterns are not blocking if you want to be able to handle button presses in the middle of the patterns.  Instead of a function that gets called once and runs through the whole pattern, imagine a function that gets called over and over and only ever takes one small step in the pattern.

Comment: (millis() < time_now + stage1)   Writing that way is a bug that causes issues when millis rolls over.  Always do this with subtraction and unsigned variables to avoid that bug.

Answer (score 0):

i fixed it by putting a return; after pattern()2; ;)